# How to validate wrong parameter being passed form the postman

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am sending a request from postman along with some wrong parameters, then also i am getting success response from the rest controller api.

I have used @Valid annotation to validate the request body.

actual request body is:-

```
{
   "vehicleModelId":432,
   "vehicleTypeId":595,
   "vehicleManufacturerId":331,
   "ptoId":582,
   "orgId":937
}
```

wrong request body:-

```
{
   "vehicleModelId":432,
   "vehicleTypeId":595,
   "vehicleManufacturerId":331,
   "ptoId":582,
   "orgId":937,
    "user":"admin"
}
```

after passing request body with extra wrong parameters it should not give success response.

Comment: The JSON you posted isn't even syntactically valid JSON, so I doubt you don't get any exception with that. But you also didn't post any code, so... If what you're sending is actually valid JSON, and if you're using Spring Boot, and if you're using Jackson, and if you didn't modify the default Jackson settings, then it's normal to not have any exception because unknown properties are ignored by default.

Comment: sorry it's a mistake. wrong request body should be like:-                                  {
 "vehicleModelId": 432,
 "vehicleTypeId": 595,
 "vehicleManufacturerId": 331,
 "ptoId": 582,
 "orgId": 937,
 "user": "admin"
}